# How to install a language pack in Ubuntu Phone Aquaris BQ 4.5

Tags: software-installation, language-support, phone

I have bought a new Ubuntu phone, and  I want to install `language-pack-br`.

On the nexus it was:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-br
```

How can I do it on my new device (Ubuntu Phone Aquaris BQ 4.5).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can easily install an additional language on the BQ phone.

OTOH, it looks like the translations into Breton to a large extent have been [completed just recently](http://projects.davidplanella.org/stats/vivid/br). The phone is shipped with the languages with highest translation coverage. I'm not sure, but I think it means that Breton will soon be added via updates.

If you want you can post a message about it to the [ubuntu-translators mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-translators).

Comment: Hi, http://projects.davidplanella.org/stats/vivid/br we do it. I hope we can install breton language with the new update of the ubuntu phone.